# Jade - why only the first button in a loop is working

Tags: javascript, button, pug

In a jade view template, there is a button created in a loop. The button call a function (in a public .js lib) and parameters are sent.
In the loop there are n items, n buttons but there is only one action when the first one is clicked.

```
each game in games
   td= moment(game.game.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss a')
   if (game.game.users.white==user.key)
      td= game.game.users.black
   else
      td= game.game.users.white
      td= game.game.id
      td
           input#username(type="hidden", value="#{user.key}", name="username")
           input#rgame(type="hidden", value="#{game.game.id}", name="rgame")
           button#resumegame Play
```

Comment: that's painful to look at, could you format the post please?

Comment: Sorry, first post and I am on iPhone (on the way)

Comment: no problems, it's much better now, at least we can see what you're talking about :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are creating buttons in a loop with the same id #resumegame.
id represents a unique element, so the event you're attaching to it on click will only work on the first button#resumegame.

One way to fix this would be to use a class instead of id, something like :

```
each game in games
   td= moment(game.game.date).format('YYYY-MM-DD h:mm:ss a')
   if (game.game.users.white==user.key)
      td= game.game.users.black
   else
      td= game.game.users.white
      td= game.game.id
      td
           input#username(type="hidden", value="#{user.key}", name="username")
           input#rgame(type="hidden", value="#{game.game.id}", name="rgame")
           button.resumegame(data-id="#{game.game.id}") Play
```

And in your js, add an event listener on the class :

```
$('.resumegame').on('click',function(){

    var gameId = $(this).data('id');

    // Do whatever you want here, 
    // you know the id of the button that has been clicked via the data-id attribute

});
```

Comment: Thank you (How can we avoid that?)

Comment: avoid what? I've offered an idea for a solution

Comment: ;) in the stackoberflow advices, it says to avoid comments with "thanks". I'll definitely try your solution. How can I call my function ( in a .js file) in your onclick event function (where is your // do whatever you want) without another click? Sorry I use to do not write function on the client side.

Comment: Hahaha, right! the best practice is usually to upvote the answer and/or accept it if it works. You're welcome in any case, let me know if it goes well

Comment: the click event will be fired when you click on any "resumegame" button

Comment: I clicked on the up arrow but nothing changes (there is a message about 15...). Of course, I'll accept your answer after testing ;) My question is now, how can I call my function which is in a .js file, what is the syntax in the onclick function (where there is the //donwhatever...)?

Comment: you mean the function is in a different js than the event listener? it's not a problem is both the js files are included in your app. For example, you included jQuery, and are able to use its functions in your custom app. so, if you replace my comment by yourFunc(gameid), and make sure that your function takes into account that many buttons will call it, you're good. without the actual function, I can't guess more than that :)